# java file.renameTo() does rename file but returns false. Why?

Tags: java, file-io

The problem is that I need the file to move before the rest of my logic will work so when the method returns false I stop execution.

However, when I check on the file in windows explorer it has a new name and it moved.

Just curious why this is happening.

here is some sample code I just tried to recreate the issue.  It's pretty much the same thing and it's working fine.

```
File testfile = new File("TestFile");

    if(!testfile.exists()){

        testfile.mkdirs();

    }

    File sample = new File("sample.txt");

    if(sample.exists()){

        boolean success = sample.renameTo(new File(testfile.getPath() + "\\" + sample.getName()));

        if(success){

            System.out.println("Moved");

        }
        else{

            System.out.println("Failed");

        }

    }
```

Edit: Solved it.  I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time with something so silly.  However, I really dont think I would have tracked this down if not for making this post.

The solution was that I was actually looping through several files to move.  When the output said it failed then the program stopped and when I looked in explorer only the first of the files was actually moved so I assumed it was moving and then returning false.  However, the issue was that I was using the wrong variable as an index and so what was happeneing was that it did successfully move the file in index 0 and then when the loop repeated the index didnt increment so it tried to move index 0 again and therefore failed.

Like I said, very stupid but thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: I'm just opening windows explorer and looking at it

Comment: [`File#renameTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) is designed to return false if the renaming is unsuccessful.  What OS/JVM are you running on?  Could you include relevant code in your question?

Comment: from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29  :  Returns:
    true if and only if the renaming succeeded; false otherwise , the relevant code is one line (boolean success = file.renameTo(new name);)

Comment: @Vulcan Are you sure about your statement. [JAVA API] says otherwise(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29)

Comment: Oops, I meant "unsuccessful," I've edited the comment.  @Mason, What OS/JVM builds are you running?

Comment: windows vista, not sure how to find jvm, i dont think they are the problem though because I use the call prior to this and it it always successful

Comment: From your comment on Gabriele's answer, it seems that the issue might be related to creating a new folder immediately before renaming the file into this folder.  Could you create a short code example to reproduce the issue, in order for others to try and recreate the issue on other operating systems?

Comment: Try running your compiled file as administiratior.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Java's `File.renameTo()` is problematic, especially on Windows, it seems. As the API documentation says:

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently
>   platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a
>   file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it
>   might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname
>   already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure
>   that the rename operation was successful.

You can use apache.commons.io library, which includes `FileUtils.moveFile()` or also the `Files.move()` method in JDK 7.

Comment: According to the API excerpt you've included, "The return value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful."  This suggests that it should always be the case that it returns true when successful, and false if unsuccessful.

Comment: the funny thing is that I use the method several other times in the same program and it consistently works until I get to the particular call where it consistently fails.  Also, I'm positive that a file with the same name does not exist because I am placing it into a new folder which I create right before the rename

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it possible that you file has a Inputstream open somewhere but has not been closed and so the rename is not working. Try closing all open streams relevant to the file object before closing.

Comment: that was the first thing I checked.  They are closed.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me

```
File file = new File("E:/Javadocs/" , "new.txt");   

File file1 = new File("E:/Javadocs/" , "myDoc.txt");          

file1.createNewFile();

if (file1.exists()){  
  System.out.println(file1.renameTo(file));
}
```

This will create a file myDoc.txt and rename it to new.txt and will print true
I've also tried with File(URI) constructor it worked fine