# Fail to rename file

Tags: java, jsp, multipartform-data

Greeting ,Currently I am using the OReilly MultipartRequest class and i want to rename the complete file name before upload.

```
MultipartRequest m = new MultipartRequest(request, Path,5024 * 1024, new FileRenamePolicy() {
                    @Override
                    public File rename(File arg0) {
                        boolean result = arg0.renameTo(new File(arg0
                                .getParentFile() + "title"));
                        if (result) {
                            System.out.println("Renamed");
                        }
                        return arg0;
                    }
                });
```

But every time result is false.Please guide me where am wrong.I am new to java Technology

Comment: is There any exception being raised ?

Comment: No it just return false value of result

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651567/java-file-renameto-does-rename-file-but-returns-false-why

Answer (score 0):

Check

1. for write-access of the JVM
2. for read-only-filesystem
3. the target files does not already exists
4. the target-filename is ok
5. the source-file exists
6. the source-file is not write-locked
7. the source-file is not open in another editor
8. the source-file can be deleted
   ... blah blah blah

Does this help?

Comment: File is uploaded with there original name, but not with I specified in the code("title").

Comment: Ok, have you checked 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 or 8?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
boolean result = arg0.renameTo(new File(arg0.getParentFile(), "title"));
```

or this ... (note file separator)

```
boolean result = arg0.renameTo(new File(arg0
        .getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "title"));
```

If it already exists you may have to delete it immediately **before** you try to rename it ...

```
File newFile = new File(arg0.getParentFile(), "title");
if (newFile.exists()) newFile.delete();
```

Comment: Still result give false value and uploaded with original file name

Comment: what is the result of adding this code as the *first two lines* in the `rename` method: `System.out.println(arg0.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath());` and `System.out.println(arg0.getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: it print C:\javaindigo\Students\WebContent\Images

Comment: And is there already a `title` file in the Images directory? You may need to delete it first! (see updated answer)

Comment: there is no file with name title in Images

Comment: This may shed some light (see accepted answer in link)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651567/java-file-renameto-does-rename-file-but-returns-false-why

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Documentation
`Returns a File object holding a new name for the specified file.` try this:

```
public File rename(File arg0) {
    return new File(arg0.getParentFile() + "title"));
}
```