# File renaming always fails although the source file is closed

Tags: java, file

I am trying to rename an existing fileSrc(i.e. old_file.pdf) to another name (i.e. new_file.pdf). However the renameTo() method returns always false. I have read that its advised to check first if the original file is open (i.e. locked) and if the destination file does not exist. Here is my source code :

```
File fileSrc = new File("old_file.pdf");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(fileSrc);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(fos!=null)
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    File fileDst = new File("new_file.pdf");    
    if(fileDst.exists()) {
        fileDst.delete();
    }
    boolean b = fileSrc.renameTo(fileDst);
    System.out.println("check : "+b);//b is always set to false
```

P.S. I am using Windows 7 for my development environment and UNIX Debian for the production environment.

Comment: Side comment: you can use [`Files.move`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) with `REPLACE_EXISTING` instead.

Comment: You can try apache.commons.io library, which includes FileUtils.moveFile() or also the Files.move()

Comment: Indeed use `Files.move`; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651567/java-file-renameto-does-rename-file-but-returns-false-why ; maybe `File fileDst = new File(fileSrc.getParentFile(), "new_file.pdf");`

Comment: If you read the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)), it says the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent. But [`Files.move`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) will move or rename a file in a platform independent manner. Take everyone's advice and use `Files.move(File)`.